# Simple HTML DOM parsing

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to parse this page http://wgl-eu.com/lottery/2153/Alabama.htm
and I'm using this code:

```
<?php
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$data = file_get_html('http://wgl-eu.com/lottery/2153/Alabama.htm');
if($data->innertext!='' and count($data->find('.last-draw-table div.no-wrap'))){
    foreach($data->find('.last-draw-table div.no-wrap') as $a){
        echo '<a>'.$a->plaintext.'</a></br>';
    }
}
$data->clear();
unset($data);
?>
```

The result is:

07 10 30 37 53
01
14 47 52 53 54
05
РР

But I need to get the result like this:

01 10 2013 07 10 30 37 53 01
28 09 2013 14 47 52 53 54 05

I dont know how to to do this but I tried a lot. Thank you.

---

07 10 30 37 53

01

14 47 52 53 54

05

РР

These are winning numbers from here http://wgl-eu.com/lottery/2153/Alabama.htm
The code above parse them well but I need to get the date + the numbers

Comment: Explain better... What means this numbers and how would you transform them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a small code that might help you :)

```
$url = "http://wgl-eu.com/lottery/2153/Alabama.htm";

$data = file_get_html($url);

// Find returns NULL if nothing found
$search = $data->find("div.box_rezult");

if($data->innertext!="" and $search ){
    foreach($search as $box_rezult){

        // Get date
        echo $box_rezult->find("td.lottery_text", 0)->plaintext;
        echo "<br/>";

        // get the table of all results
        $table = $box_rezult->find("table.last-draw-table", 0);

        // get winning numbers
        echo $table->children(2)->children(0)->plaintext;
        echo "<br/>";

        echo $table->children(2)->children(1)->plaintext;
        echo "<br/>";

        echo $table->children(2)->children(2)->plaintext;
        echo "<br/>";
    }
}
$data->clear();
unset($data);

OUTPUT
======
Last Draw - 01 10 2013
07 10 30 37 53
01
03 
Last Draw - 28 09 2013
14 47 52 53 54
05
РР
```

[PHPfiddle DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/p1v-jhz)

Also, refer to [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) for more details